# Loss function for simple Reinforcement Learning algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

This question comes from watching the following video on TensorFlow and Reinforcement Learning from Google I/O 18: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1A3NTttvBA

Here they train a very simple RL algorithm to play the game of Pong.

In the slides they use, the loss is defined like this ( approx @ 11m 25s ):

```
loss = -R(sampled_actions * log(action_probabilities))
```

Further they show the following code ( approx @ 20m 26s):

```
# loss
cross_entropies = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
    onehot_labels=tf.one_hot(actions, 3), logits=Ylogits)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(rewards * cross_entropies)

# training operation
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, decay=0.99)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Now my question is this; They use the +1 for winning and -1 for losing as rewards. In the code that is provided, any cross entropy loss that's multiplied by a negative reward will be very low? And if the training operation is using the optimizer to minimize the loss, well then the algorithm is trained to lose?

Or is there something fundamental I'm missing ( probably because of my very limited mathematical skills )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question Corey.  I am also wondering exactly what this popular loss function in RL actually means.  I've seen many implementations of it, but many contradict each other.  For my understanding, it means this:

Loss = - log(pi) * A

Where A is the advantage compared to a baseline case.  In Google's case, they used a baseline of 0, so A = R.  This is multiplied by that specific action at that specific time, so in your above example, actions were one hot encoded as [1, 0, 0].  We will ignore the 0s and only take the 1.  Hence we have the above equation.

**If you intuitively calculate this loss for a negative reward:**

Loss = - (-1) * log(P)

But for any P less than 1, log of that value will be negative.  Therefore, you have a negative loss which can be interpreted as "very good", but really doesn't make physical sense.

**The correct way:**

However in my opinion, and please others correct me if I'm wrong, you do not calculate the loss directly.  You take the ***gradient*** of the loss.  That is, you take the derivative of -log(pi)*A.

Therefore, you would have:

-(d(pi) / pi) * A

Now, if you have a large negative reward, it will translate to a very large loss.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Aah I think I understand. But does this mean I should use log(P)  instead of calculating the cross entropy loss like they do in the code? Or will the two achieve the same?

Comment: Hi Covey.  In any machine learning algorithm, the model is trained by calculating the gradient of the loss to identify the slope of highest descent.  So you use cross entropy loss as in the video, and when you train the model, it evaluates the derivative of the loss function rather than the loss function explicitly.  I did not watch the video, but I assume they have one line of code like "optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer".  This line is what kind of gradient to compute.  Then they would use "optimizer.minimize(loss)".  Which is 2 commands: "compute gradients" and "apply gradients"

Comment: So in optimizer.minimize(loss), tensorflow computes the gradients with respect to the loss function, and then it applies the gradients to the weights of the model via the gradient descent method stated by your optimizer.  The cross entropy loss is never actually explicitly computed.